# Different performance between Java and c# code when testing URL

Tags: c#, http, timeout

When running the following Java code, I get very accurate and consistent results in determining if the web page I'm testing is up.

```
protected synchronized boolean checkUrl(HttpURLConnection connection){
    boolean error = false;
    //HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    try{
        if(connection != null){
            connection.connect();

            //200 is the expected HTTP_OK response
            error = processResponseCode(connection.getResponseCode());

            connection.disconnect();
        } else{
            error = false;
        }

    }catch(java.net.UnknownHostException uhe){
        ...     } 
    catch(Exception e){
        ...     }

    return error;
}
```

The closest match to the Java pattern in c# has much higher results of false positives (mostly due to timeouts - which has a default period of 100000ms).

```
protected bool connectedToUrl = false;
        response = null;

        HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.getUri());
        webreq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse res = null;// webreq.GetResponse();

        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.getUri()) as WebRequest;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            if (request != null)
            {
                // Get response 
                res = webreq.GetResponse();

                connectedToUrl = processResponseCode(res);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Fatal(getFatalMessage());

                string error = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        return connectedToUrl;
    }
```

I have tried various patterns in c# to match the effectiveness of the quoted Java code, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this:

```
res = webreq.GetResponse();
connectedToUrl = processResponseCode(res);
```

to

```
using (WebResponse res = webreq.GetResponse()) 
{
    connectedToUrl = processResponseCode(res);
}
```

(Remove the declaration from earlier.)

Until you haven't closed/disposed the response (or it's been finalized), it's holding onto  the connection. You can only have a certain number (2 by default, I believe) of connections to any one host at a time, hence the timeouts. When you dispose the response, it allows another request to use the same connection.

Comment: the processResponseCode is looking to the response code (401, 404, 200,...) when checking the URL.

Comment: So should I add "res.Close();" inside the using(...) block?

Comment: No - the point of the using statement is that it's like a try/finally which calls Dispose in the finally block.

Comment: Update: the timeouts are gone.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because you're not closing any of the request objects.

Comment: Would they not just go out of scope?

Comment: No, it's not enough. Make sure you call *any* close method you can find on all the http-related objects you use ;)

Comment: There's some pooling going, which is the reason you have to close.

Comment: put a using block around the request?

Answer (score 1):

Also this:

```
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw e;
   }
```

Does nothing but destroy the stack trace on an exception that's been bubbled upwards. If you have error handling elsewhere in your code I suggest removing the try catch block. Otherwise you should log the exception and move on. Don't just catch it to throw it.

Comment: Or, when rethrowing use the proper syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid#380833

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the GregorianCalendar in the C# version :-)

Why do you have two Request Objects in the C# version?

Comment: LOL. That's the best diagnosis I've seen today.

Comment: I'm working on it, just waiting for my submission to be incorporated in framework 5. ;)

Comment: I have 2 objects because one should have been commented out. Its the 4th iteration and had a few sloppy artifacts.